# Cannot see hard drive after failed Truecrypt decryption

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, truecrypt

I was decrypting Truecrypt external drive and at 25% it said there was a corrupt data so it replaced it with random data. After that the decryption failed completely. I deferred the decryption and restarted the computer.

Now the drive is not even recognized anywhere, not even mentioning the mounting.
Resuming the decryption gives error that the encrypted volume cannot be found.

Is there a way to somehow recognize the drive or a program to run diagnostic on corrupted encrypted sectors?

EDIT: Using Windows 7 OS

Comment: In other words, do I have a brick right now?

Comment: Yes;  The process corrupted the data.

Comment: @HenryTheLeast can you edit your question to include the operating system are you using?

Comment: Edited: it is Windows 7